# Was the KGB, at least after 1975, actually an effective institution?

Tags: soviet-union, kgb, intelligence

There were several major events that the [KGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KGB) either failed to predict or misjudged, e.g., it

- underestimated the [Solidarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solidarity_(Polish_trade_union)) movement in Poland
- failed to predict the [fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fall_of_the_Berlin_Wall) of the Berlin Wall
- did not foresee the [fall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dissolution_of_the_Soviet_Union) of the USSR itself

I can also add massive disasters with Chernobyl and the outcome of the Afghan War, which were also due to the KGB failing to provide accurate info and predict dangers.

Was the KGB, at least after 1975, actually an efficient institution in any way? Or was it just a propaganda tool and a provider of sinecures for its staff?

Comment: Do you want your intelligence agencies to be efficient or effective? Perhaps they were quite efficient yet not very effective. I’ll note most other countries failed to grasp just what was happening as well.

Comment: That;s a nice comment, ty.

Comment: Your question is rather naive (believing that the political leadership always **heads** the advice given to them by these services) and superficial (it was not the KGB choice that the Brezhnev Doctrine was no longer being inforced ; not even the east german government properly understood what effect the order for the 10 of November would have - and they didn't inform the SU beforehand ; Chernobyl was caused by a technical problem ; the  Afghan war the responsiblity of the military GRU).

Comment: Chernobyl was caused by a technical problem that was covered by KGB for years before it happened. Also domestic nuclear security was one of KGB fields of work. The decision to invade Afghanistan in 1979 was made by a small group within the Politburo led by KGB Chairman Yuri Andropov. He persuaded Leonid Brezhnev this would secure Soviet influence. Sorry, mate, looks you have zero idea what you are talking about.

Comment: This reads as "if s/God/the KGB is all-powerful, then whence cometh evil?" One might as well ask why the KGB did not prevent the Brezhnev stagnation or win the Space Race.

Comment: Quite the opposite, it wasn't powerful enough in the real world, but it produced a powerful image, these are different things. So my question in a way is - to how much the power was a fake when dealing with real difficult issues

Comment: The secret ingredient for such services is to have peaple **believe** that they are all knowing and all powerfull so that everyone will say to themselfs: [resistance is futile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg#%22Resistance_is_futile%22).

Comment: How do you measure effective?  "effective" is like "pretty" there are no standard units of measure.  And effective for what purpose?  Your question measures presumed failures without any knowledge of successes or attempts, which would confound even the most trivial measures of effectiveness.  An interesting pub discussion, but fundamentally a subjective/opinion question.

Comment: I agree that 'effectiveness' is a subjective term and can be difficult to measure, especially when it comes to something as multifaceted and secretive as an intelligence agency like the KGB. I'm interested in understanding more about its various aspects—intelligence gathering, political repression, state security, etc.—and how successful it was in these areas.

Comment: Given the fact that they make the president since Andropov, I would say pretty effective. Even today Putin doesn't have to worry about internal turmoil.

Comment: @Jos After Andropov (16 months) came Gorbachov (1985-1991) then Yeltsin (1991-1999) - both (in a period of 14 years) of which were **not** KGB. So where are your 'facts' coming from?

Comment: Yeltsin\s rule was not in the USSR altogether. Obviously KGB is USSR service and talking about KGB we discuss USSR period. Don't waste if you have no idea even about the topic of discussion.